# C# chart with real time data

Tags: c#, charts, dynamic-data

I already found some examples for drawing a chart with real time data in one of the links below in the comments. My question now is, can I also draw in real time things such as chart labels, axis and other related things?

---

Actually what I was looking for was to draw a chart for real-time data. Searching for real-time instead of dynamic data, I found my answer. Now I have another question. Is there a way to also add text in the chart that will change dynamically as the chart draws?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the .net charting controls

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

As for updating the charts over time, just refresh the chart periodically.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it is very helpful. I've seen the Windows Forms Samples in the above link and there are some samples for dynamic data. I'll just have to test them to see it that's what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified whether it's WPF / WinForms or Silverlight, I'll give you a WPF/Silverlight answer.

1. There are free charting controls available like in WPF/Silverlight Toolkit or Visifire(not sure if it's free anymore). That + Databinding + (optionally) the MVVM pattern (which - for me personally makes things easier)
2. You can use an ObservableCollection to store data that's changing over time
3. You can use the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to notify the GUI that the data has been updated

Comment: It's WinForms. Using 2. or 3., will I be able to create a chart that will change automatically or do I have to handle the events and make the chart change manually?

Answer (score 0):

Today, In 2022, I use [ScotPlot](https://scottplot.net). It is fast and has tone of features.